# C string append

Tags: c, string, append

I'm looking for an efficient method for appending multiple strings.
The way it should work is C++ std::string::append or JAVA StringBuffer.append.

I wrote a function which actually reallocs previous source pointer and does strcat.

I believe this is not an efficient method as compiler may implement this free and malloc.

Other way I could think of (like std::vector) is allocate memory in bulk (1KB for eg) and do strcpy. In that case every append call will check if the total required allocation is more than (1200 bytes) the amount allocated in bulk, realloc to 2KB. But in that case there will be some memory wasted.

I'm looking for a balance between the above but the preference is performance.

What other approaches are possible. Please suggest.

Comment: [`strcat`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcat/)?

Comment: strcat is of no help, it does not allocate any space for you, does no bounds checking for you, and is quite inefficient unless you remember the end of the previous string.

Comment: Concatenation is generally simply the *wrong idiom* in C. Don't use it unless you have no other options. (It's inefficient in other languages too, but those other languages completely lack efficient alternatives, so it's acceptable.) By the way, if you want to use C++ or Java idioms, use one of those languages, not C. Trying to translate idioms between computer languages is just about as nonsensical as trying to translate them between human languages.

Comment: I used C++ and JAVA idiom to mention what I'm looking for. operator+() in both JAVA and C++ returns a new string/String instead of extending the already present string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C: What is the best and fastest way to concatenate strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21880730/c-what-is-the-best-and-fastest-way-to-concatenate-strings)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would add each string to a list, and add the length of each new string to a running total.  Then, when you're done, allocate space for that total, walk the list and strcpy each string to the newly allocated space.

Answer (score 2):

The classical approach is to double the buffer every time it is too small.

Start out with a "reasonable" buffer, so you don't need to do `realloc()`s for sizes 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 which are going to be hit by a large number of your strings.

Starting out at 1024 bytes means you will have one `realloc()` if you hit 2048, a second if you hit 4096, and so on. If rampant memory consumption scares you, cap the growth rate once it hits something suitably big, like 65536 bytes or whatever, it depends on your data and memory tolerance.

Also make sure you buffer the current length, so you can do `strcpy()` without having to walk the string to find the length, first.

Comment: You should mention that the reason for this is to avoid `O(n^2)` worst-case copying performance on repeated concatenation.

Comment: @unwind: We still need strlen to find out the string length to check if the new string to be appended overflows... Don't we?

Comment: @Mayank - Now you are back to the inefficiencies of C strings. Java and C++ does this by remembering the length of each string and the size of each buffer. They don't have to count the chars all the time! Higher level ops **can** be more efficient.

Comment: Another efficiency is to maintain a pointer to the end of the string.  A lot of time can be wasted by searching each time for the terminating '\0' character.

Comment: Well, personally I like @Mark Jones's solution. Any comments?

Comment: The drawback to my solution, though, is that the strings that are added to the list must not be altered in any way, including freeing their memory. And they can't hang out on the stack either.  Be very careful.

Answer (score 0):

Sample function to concatenate strings

```
void
addToBuffer(char **content, char *buf) {
    int textlen, oldtextlen;
    textlen =  strlen(buf);
    if (*content == NULL)
        oldtextlen = 0;
    else
        oldtextlen = strlen(*content);
    *content = (char *) realloc( (void *) *content, (sizeof(char)) * (oldtextlen+textlen+1));
    if ( oldtextlen != 0 ) {
        strncpy(*content + oldtextlen, buf, textlen + 1);
    } else {
        strncpy(*content, buf, textlen + 1);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    char *content = NULL;
    addToBuffer(&content, "test");
    addToBuffer(&content, "test1");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
typedef struct Stringbuffer {
    int capacity;     /* Maximum capacity. */
    int length;       /* Current length (excluding null terminator). */
    char* characters; /* Pointer to characters. */
} Stringbuffer;

BOOL StringBuffer_init(Stringbuffer* buffer) {
    buffer->capacity = 0;
    buffer->length = 0;
    buffer->characters = NULL;
}

void StringBuffer_del(Stringbuffer* buffer) {
    if (!buffer)
        return;

    free(buffer->characters);

    buffer->capacity = 0;
    buffer->length = 0;
    buffer->characters = NULL;
}

BOOL StringBuffer_add(Stringbuffer* buffer, char* string) {
    int len;
    int new_length;

    if (!buffer)
        return FALSE;

    len = string ? strlen(string) : 0;

    if (len == 0)
        return TRUE;

    new_length = buffer->length + len;

    if (new_length >= new_capacity) {
        int new_capacity;

        new_capacity = buffer->capacity;

        if (new_capacity == 0)
            new_capacity = 16;

        while (new_length >= new_capacity)
            new_capacity *= 2;

        new_characters = (char*)realloc(buffer->characters, new_capacity);
        if (!new_characters)
            return FALSE;

        buffer->capacity = new_capacity;
        buffer->characters = new_characters;
    }

    memmove(buffer->characters + buffer->length, string, len);
    buffer->length = new_length;
    buffer->characters[buffer->length] = '\0';

    return TRUE;
}
```