# C: What is the best and fastest way to concatenate strings

Tags: c, string, performance, concatenation

I currently concatenate strings in c using the `strcat()` function from `string.h` library.

I thought about it, and I got to a conclusion that it should be very expensive function, as before it starts to concatenate, it has to iterate over the char array until it finds the `'\0'` char.

For example, if I concatenate the string `"horses"` 1000 times using `strcat()`, I'll have to pay
`(1 + 2 + 3 + ... + 1000) * strlen("horses") = (1000*1001)/2 * 6 = 3003000`

I thought about the non-standard way, of maintaining an integer with the string length, and then sending to `strcat()` the pointer to the end of the string:

```
strcat(dest + dest_len, "string");
```

In this case, I'll pay only `1000 * strlen("horses") = 1000 * 6 = 6000`.

`6000` is 500x smaller than `3003000`, so it can be very critical for performance if you make a lot of such concatenations.

Is there some more standard way to do it, looking better than my solution?

Comment: if you have too many strings to concatenate you can make use of `snprintf(buf, len, "%s%s%s", str1, str2, str3)`

Comment: This sounds like premature optimisation to me. Are you aware how fast it is to iterate over the characters in a string?

Comment: If you are maintaining the length of the string then you are also doing the same thing..just the difference is that you are doing it in your code rather than `strcat()` doing it for you!

Comment: @Nullpointer The difference is that `strcat()` needs to iterate the destination string (O(n)) to find the end-of-string, while maintaining the length of the string allows the same operation in constant O(1) time

Comment: " thought about the non-standard way, of maintaining an integer with the string length, and then sending to strcat() the pointer to the end of the string" : that's actually how Java implement the string object (with also a hash and offset index)

Comment: @Andreas what if your string is user input?( which happens most of the cases!) Then you can't ask user to provide the length!

Comment: @Nullpointer Sure, at one point in time you need to find out the length, most likely when initializing a string object. But further operations *could* be faster then.

Comment: you are right! but then finding out length in your code is going to add same time overhead even if you save some time in `strcat()` by passing string length!

Comment: On a side note, you might want to look into the [Ropes alternative to Strings](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.14.9450&rep=rep1&type=pdf) for a completely different approach

Comment: This reminds me of Joel Spolsky's article, [_Back to Basics_](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html), particularly the bit about _Shlemiel the painter's algorithm_.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Joel Spolsky, in his [*Back to Basics*](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html) article, describes the problem of inefficient string concatenation with `strcat` as the *Shlemiel the painter's algorithm* (read the article, it's quite good).  As an example of inefficient code, he gives this example, which runs in O(n<sup>2</sup>) time:

> ```
> char bigString[1000];     /* I never know how much to allocate... */
> bigString[0] = '\0';
> strcat(bigString,"John, ");
> strcat(bigString,"Paul, ");
> strcat(bigString,"George, ");
> strcat(bigString,"Joel ");
> ```

It's not really a problem to walk over the first string *the first time*;  since we've already got to walk over the second string, the runtime of *one* `strcat` is linear in the length of the result. Multiple `strcat`s is problematic though, because we walk over the previously concatenated results again and again.  He provides this alternative:

> How do we fix this? A few smart C programmers implemented their own
>   `mystrcat` as follows:
>
> ```
> char* mystrcat( char* dest, char* src )
> {
>      while (*dest) dest++;
>      while (*dest++ = *src++);
>      return --dest;
> }
> ```
>
> What have we done here? At very little extra cost we're returning a
>   pointer to the end of the new, longer string. That way the code that
>   calls this function can decide to append further without rescanning
>   the string:
>
> ```
> char bigString[1000];     /* I never know how much to allocate... */
> char *p = bigString;
> bigString[0] = '\0';
> p = mystrcat(p,"John, ");
> p = mystrcat(p,"Paul, ");
> p = mystrcat(p,"George, ");
> p = mystrcat(p,"Joel ");
> ```
>
> This is, of course, linear in performance, not n-squared, so it
>   doesn't suffer from degradation when you have a lot of stuff to
>   concatenate.

Of course, this is what you can do if you want to use standard C strings.  The alternative that you're describing of caching the length of the string and using a special concatenation function (e.g., calling `strcat` with slightly different arguments) is sort of a variation on Pascal strings, which Joel also mentioned:

> The designers of Pascal were aware of this problem and "fixed" it by
>   storing a byte count in the first byte of the string. These are called
>   Pascal Strings. They can contain zeros and are not null terminated.
>   Because a byte can only store numbers between 0 and 255, Pascal
>   strings are limited to 255 bytes in length, but because they are not
>   null terminated they occupy the same amount of memory as ASCIZ
>   strings. The great thing about Pascal strings is that you never have
>   to have a loop just to figure out the length of your string. Finding
>   the length of a string in Pascal is one assembly instruction instead
>   of a whole loop. It is monumentally faster.
>
> …
>
> For a long time, if you wanted to put a Pascal string literal in your
>   C code, you had to write:
>
> ```
> char* str = "\006Hello!";
> ```
>
> Yep, you had to count the bytes by hand, yourself, and hardcode it
>   into the first byte of your string. Lazy programmers would do this,
>   and have slow programs:
>
> ```
> char* str = "*Hello!";
> str[0] = strlen(str) - 1;
> ```

Comment: @Groo I'm pretty sure that by virtue of the string literal in `char* str = "*Hello!";`, the string is automatically null terminated.  To get one that *wasn't* null terminated, you'd actually need to create a character array and put the six characters 'H', 'e', ..., 'o', '!' in.

Comment: Ok, of course, this snippet was showing how to get a Pascal string *in C*, I got it all wrong. Never mind. :)

Comment: In, `mystrcat`, you must protect against overrunning the end of `dest` if adding `src` would exceed the space available to `dest`. Good example, but may be worth passing a pointer to the number of characters that remain available in `dest` to prevent against the possibility.

Comment: It is really weird to me, why `strcat()` was made so inefficient... I thought C creators are more thoughtfull...

Comment: @71GA Maybe it's a case of [worse is better](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worse_is_better).

Answer (score 20):

If you want it easy, fast, general, *and* safe, I suggest using the `open_memstream()` function (it's a part of the POSIX-2008 standard, unfortunately it did not make it into the C11 standard, thought). It works like this:

First, you hand it the address of a pointer and a size

```
char* result = NULL;
size_t resultSize = 0;
FILE* stream = open_memstream(&result, &resultSize);
```

the return value is a file stream just as if you had used `fopen()` to open a file. As such, you can use the entire arsenal of `fprintf()` & co. to stream anything you like to your memory buffer, which is automatically allocated and managed for you. Most importantly, it also keeps track of the size of the accumulated string, so it does not have to rescan it to compute its size.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    fprintf(stream, "current number is %d, or 0x%x\n", i, i);
}
```

Finally, you close the stream, which will update your result pointer and the size variable to reflect the actual amount of string data written.

```
fclose(stream);
//Now you have a zero terminated C-string in result, and also its size in resultSize.
//You can do with it whatever you like.
//Just remember to free it afterwards:
free(result);
```

Comment: This is similar to StringIO in Python concept right?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai Yes, it's the same idea implemented for a different language.

Answer (score 3):

This is a late answer, but I just have come across the same issue. To find a starting point, I decided to re-read the man pages for `strcpy`, `strncpy`, `strlen`, `strnlen`, `strcat` and `strncat`.

I have almost missed it, but fortunately ... there is an interesting passage in `man strcpy` on my development system (Debian stretch). Citing it (formatting mine):

> `strlcpy()`
>
> Some systems (the BSDs, Solaris, and others) provide the following
>   function:
>
> ```
> size_t strlcpy(char *dest, const char *src, size_t size);
> ```
>
> This function is similar to `strncpy()`, but it copies at most `size-1`
>   bytes to `dest`, always adds a terminating null byte, and does not pad
>   the target with (further) null bytes. This function fixes some of the
>   problems of `strcpy()` and `strncpy()`, but the caller must still handle
>   the possibility of data loss if `size` is too small. **The return value
>   of the function is the length of `src`**, which allows truncation to be
>   easily detected: if the return value is greater than or equal to `size`,
>   truncation occurred. If loss of data matters, the caller must either
>   check the arguments before the call, or test the function return
>   value. **`strlcpy()` is not present in `glibc` and is not standardized by
>   `POSIX`, but is available on Linux via the `libbsd` library.**

Yes, you are reading this right: The man page of a glibc function contains a hint to a non-standardized function in another library which does the job better. This might prove how important this issue is.

By the way, I'll never get why the designers of the `str(n)cpy()` functions didn't chose the number of bytes copied or a pointer to the new *end* of `dest` as return value. Returning just `dest` seems silly because those functions do not change that parameter, so in every case it is still known to the caller when the function has returned, and hence this choice does not make any sense. Did I miss something?

Until I knew about `strlcpy()`, I mostly have used my own string concatenation functions, something like @Joshua Taylor has shown in his answer. This idea has its own problems, though:

Scanning / copying strings byte by byte might be very inefficient. Depending on the target CPU, we should use the 32-bit or even 64-bit registers and copy multiple bytes at a time. Of course, this makes the function more complicated since we have to check if enough bytes remain to be copied, and if not, use the next smaller register size. To further improve performance, we should use assembly code to implement our function.

AFAIK, libraries like glibc and libbsd have it implemented that way. So it might be best to use the libbsd implementation. I have not done performance measurements, though.

Comment: While this long discussion is advocating a good solution to a famous problem, it bears very little connection to the OP's question. The issue is how to reduce the quadratic complexity of concatenating thousands of strings into the same destination array, assumed to be large enough.

Comment: @chqrlie The OP states that `strcat` scans the existing string for `0` before actually appending the other string, and complains about the associated performance loss. Then he shows how he could reduce the problem order from quadratic to linear by maintaining a temporary variable that always contains the length of the existing string. To maintain that variable, `strlen` must be called on the appended string in every pass. `strlcpy` saves those superfluous `strlen` calls. The order remains linear of course, but CPU time may be reduced by somewhere between 30% to 50% (educated guess).

Answer (score 2):

To concatenate multiple strings, code may use `strlen()` and `memcpy()` which are both often well optimized functions.

With this approach, easy to add an inexpensive `size` limit.
Given the real chance the destination buffer may overflow otherwise, a size limit is essential.

Run time proportional to the sum of string lengths: O(len(S[0]) + len(S[1]) + len(S[2]) + ...)

```
char *strsncat(char *dest, size_t size, char * strs[], size_t n) {
  assert(size > 0);
  size--;
  char *p = dest;
  while (n-- > 0) {
    size_t len = strlen(*strs);
    if (len >= size) {
      len = size;
    }
    size -= len;
    memcpy(p, *strs, len);
    strs++;
    p += len;
  }
  *p = '\0';
  return dest;
}

void cat_test(void) {
  char dest[10];
  char *strs[]  = { "Red", "Green", "Blue" };
  printf("'%s'\n",strsncat(dest, sizeof dest, strs, sizeof strs/sizeof strs[0]));
  // 'RedGreenB'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have two string: `s1` and `s2` with length `l1` and `l2` Concatenation means that you should generate a new string `s3` with length `l1+l2`. The time complexity of this operation is `O(l1+l2)`. From this point of view, `strcat()` seems to be the best choice.

However, if you want to indicate the state that two strings are concatenated, then you only need to record their pointers, which is `O(1)`. A simple example would be like this:

```
typedef struct ConcatStr {
    char* str1;
    char* str2;
} ConcatStr;
ConcatStr myStrcat( char* str1, char* str2 )
{
    ConcatStr cstr;
    cstr.str1 = str1;
    cstr.str2 = str2;
}
```

Comment: A single `strcat` is linear, yes.  If there are multiple operations though (e.g., `strcat(bigString,"John, "); strcat(bigString,"Paul, ");`, then you end up doing O(n^2) work by the end, because you'll walk over the previously concatenated portion again.  For the single case, though, you're right: the linear performance is fine.

Comment: Yeah, I did not think of multiple concatenations. Indeed, you can record multiple pointer addresses and do the concatenation at last.
However, it may result in ugly code. Thus, I think the best solution is problem-dependent.

Comment: I think the aesthetics of the code really depends on how well the abstraction is constructed.  If it's a matter of keeping an extra length variable around and updating it manually, then yes, the code will be kind of ugly.  If it's a bit more encapsulated (a structure with a length field and a char\*, and wrappers for the necessary functions), then it won't look so terrible.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I do, and it's faster than strcat, but I don't know how it compares to other solutions.  Let's say you have an array of 1000 strings and want to concatenate them with spaces between, and you have a 100,000 character buffer to hold it.

```
int L=0;
char buffer[100000];
char *str[1000]; // assume this is already populated
for (int i=0; i<1000; i++) // 1000 or whatever number you actually have
{
 L+=sprintf(buffer+L,"%s ",str[i]); // this is the important part
}
```

sprintf will return the number of characters written, and keep advancing the pointer buffer+L.
This does NOT have any safety checking.  You can check whether L exceeds 100000, but that's on you.  If buffer+L is beyond the end of the string, it will crash your app.

Answer (score 0):

I use this variant which is more of a drop-in replacement for strcat, though not exactly:

```
char* mystrcat(char** dest, const char* src) {

    int i = 0;
    char cur;
    while(1) {
        cur = src[i];
        (*dest)[i] = cur;
        if(cur == 0) break;
        i++;
    }

    *dest += i;

    return *dest;
}
```

The return value is not important here.
A char array `char str[32]` does not contain storage for an actual pointer to the characters (to get a pointer to again), so you can do:

```
char str[32];
char* pStr = str; //storage for pointer
mystrcat(&pStr, "bla");
mystrcat(&pStr, "de");
mystrcat(&pStr, "bla\n");
printf(str);
```

or

```
myfunction(char* pStr) {

    mystrcat(&pStr, "bla");
    mystrcat(&pStr, "de");
    mystrcat(&pStr, "bla\n");
}

char str[32];
myfunction(str);
printf(str);
```

because storage for the pointer is now created on the stack for myfunction().

A length constrained version would be:

```
char* mystrcat(char** dest, const char* src, int max) {

    int i = 0;
    char cur;
    while(1) {
        if(i == max) {
            (*dest)[i] = 0;
            break;
        }
        cur = src[i];
        (*dest)[i] = cur;
        if(cur == 0) break;
        i++;
    }

    *dest += i;

    return *dest;
}
```

Comment: What happens if the characters in `src` cause you to write beyond the end of `dest[i]` (e.g. `str`)?

Comment: Same as what would happen with `strcat()` in such a case; memory that was not allocated for the purpose gets overwritten. So use big enough buffers, do input validation, or use a length constrained version.

Comment: Your length constrained version is confusing, the size argument must be computed from the updated pointer in a non trivial way. A better API seems possible.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

https://john.nachtimwald.com/2017/02/26/efficient-c-string-builder/

It helped me Copy an char** to clipboard in the blink of an eye

```
    str_builder_t *sb;
     sb = str_builder_create();

                        int colcnt=0;
                        for (int i=0;i<nrF;i++)  // nrF = number of Fileds 
                    {
                            //strcat(DATA,sqlite_array[i]);
                     str_builder_add_str(sb, sqlite_array[i], 0); 
                            if (colcnt<nrofcolumns)  // my list view 
                                {
                            str_builder_add_str(sb, "\t", 0); 
                                colcnt++;

                            }
                                if (colcnt==nrofcolumns) 
                            {

                            str_builder_add_str(sb, "\n", 0); 
                                    colcnt=0;
                            }

                    }

    HANDLE  glob =GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED,str_builder_len(sb)+1);
    memcpy(glob,str_builder_peek(sb),str_builder_len(sb)+1);
    OpenClipboard(NULL);
    EmptyClipboard();
    SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT,glob);
    CloseClipboard();
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple safe and efficient concatenation function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *strwrite(char *dest, size_t size, size_t *ppos, const char *src) {
    size_t pos = *ppos;
    if (pos < size) {
        size_t len = strlen(src);
        if (pos + len < size)
            memcpy(dest + pos, src, len + 1);
            *ppos += len;
        } else {
            memcpy(dest + pos, src, size - pos - 1);
            dest[size - 1] = '\0';
            *ppos = size - 1;
        }
    }
    return dest;
}

int main() {
    char dest[10];
    size_t pos = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        strwrite(dest, sizeof dest, &pos, "Test");
    }
    printf("%s\n", dest);   // TestTestT
    return 0;
}
```

On POSIX systems, the code can be simplified with `strnlen()`:

```
char *strwrite(char *dest, size_t size, size_t *ppos, const char *src) {
    size_t pos = *ppos;
    if (pos < size) {
        size_t len = strnlen(src, size - pos - 1);
        memcpy(dest + pos, src, len);
        pos += len;
        dest[pos] = '\0';
        *ppos = pos;
    }
    return dest;
}
```