# Building very long repetitive string in C

Tags: c, string

Suppose I want to generate a very long, repetitive string, such as

```
"foo bar bar bar bar ... bar"
```

where `bar` occurs 1,000 times in the final result. What would be the easiest way to do this without having memory leaks?

Comment: Plaster, use a lot of plaster.

Comment: `malloc` will return a null pointer if it fails to allocate the requested memory, so you could simply try to allocate as much memory as you need and see if the OS lets you.

Comment: How are memory leaks related to this?

Comment: @mafso Naive approaches could involve lots of copying that could lead to memory leaks.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor, I'm not sure if this is what Koz thinks of (if that's the point, pretty much every question about how to accomplish something in C could include the phrase "without having memory leaks"). I'm unsure if actually something else is being asked (and the term memory leak is used wrongly). Some languages have short idioms to do this, so probably people may want to look for this and this question can be useful. But it needs improvement and clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that came to my mind is:

```
char *string = malloc(4004);
int i;
strcpy(string, "foo");
for(i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    strcat(string, " bar");
```

Comment: This will be slow, because `strcat()` implicitly does a `strlen()` inside the loop. Replace it with `strcpy(string + 3 + 3 * i, "bar")`.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker; complexity != speed. But otherwise, I agree.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Impressive. Thanks for the advice. I know it is slow. I just wanted to give him an idea of how he could do it. There are many possible ways.

Comment: Joel Spolsky discussed this issue: [Back to Basics](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html).  Also see [C: What is the best and fastest way to concatenate strings](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21880730/1281433).