# How can I implement a function to concatenate to a char* and not char array?

Tags: c, concatenation

How can I implement a function that will concatenate something to a char* (not char array)?
Example of what I want:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  char* current_line;
  char temp[1];
  sprintf(temp, "%c", 'A');
  // This causes a seg fault. I of course don't want that, so how do I get this to work properly?
  strcat(current_line, temp);
  return 0;
}
```

How can I fix this to work properly (and please, tell me if I need to add anything to my question or point me in the right direction because I couldn't find anything)?

Edit: I made this but it seg faults

```c
char* charpointercat(char* mystr, char* toconcat) {
  char ret[strlen(mystr) + 1];
  for(int i = 0; mystr[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    ret[i] = mystr[i];
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "concatenate something to a char*"? Where do you expect the result to be stored?

Comment: The result would be stored in the char*

Comment: You can't store a string in a `char*`. A `char*` can only hold a pointer to a character. What you can do is create a `char *` that happens to point to the first character in a hunk of memory that represents a string. You need to allocate that memory somewhere, somehow, which will almost surely involve creating an array.

Comment: Well then how does `char* a = "Hello, world!"` work?

Comment: @Dock: In the example of your previous comment, the string literal`"Hello, world!"` is stored in a **read-only** memory location that was loading from your executable file. Your line of code will cause `a` to point to this read-only memory location. However, you need memory which can be written to, for what you want to do.

Comment: OK. I just didn't want to get a buffer overflow so I avoided using an array

Comment: In `char* a = "Hello, world!";`, the string "Hello, world!" will be somewhere in memory, and `a` will technically hold a pointer to the 'H' at the start of it.  When someone says a `char *` holds a string, usually that's what they mean anyway though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the first code you posted it seems like you want to concatenate a char to the end of a string... This code will return a **new** string that consists of the first one followed by the second, it wont change the parameter.

```
char* charpointercat(char* mystr, char toconcat) {
    char *ret = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(mystr) + 2));
    int i;
    for(i = 0; mystr[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        ret[i] = mystr[i];
     }
     ret[i] = toconcat;
     ret[i + 1] = '\0';
     return ret;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have 3 problems:

1. You do not allocate memory for `current_line` at all!
2. You do not allocate enough memory for `temp`.
3. You return a pointer to a local variable from `charpointercat`.

The first one should be obvious, and was explained in comments:
`char *current_line` only holds a pointer to some bytes, but you need to allocate actual bytes if you want to store something with a function like `stracat`.

For the secoond one, note that `sprintf(temp, "%c", 'A');` needs at least `char temp[2]` as it will use one byte for the "A", and one byte for terminating null character.

Since `sprintf` does not know how big `temp` is, it writes beyond it and that is how you get the segfault.

As for your `charpointercat` once the function exits, `ret` no longer exists.

To be more precise:
An array in C is represented by a pointer (a memory address) of its first item (cell).

So, the line `return ret;` does not return a copy of all the bytes in `ret` but only a pointer to the first byte.

But that memory address is only valid inside `charpointercat` function.
Once you try to use it outside, it is "undefined behavior", so anything can happen, including segfault.

There are two ways to fix this:

1. Learn how to use `malloc` and allocate memory on the heap.
2. Pass in a third array to the function so it can store the result there (same way you do with `sprintf`).

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
char* charpointercat(char* mystr, char* toconcat) {
  size_t l1,l2;
  //Get lengths of strings
  l1=strlen(mystr);
  l2=strlen(toconcat);
  //Allocate enough memory for both
  char * ret=malloc(l1+l2+1);
  strcpy(ret,mystr);
  strcat(ret,toconcat);
  //Add null terminator
  ret[l1+l2]='\0';
  return ret;
}

int main(){
  char * p=charpointercat("Hello","World");
  printf("%s",p);
  //Free the memory
  free(p); 
}
```

Comment: Why not simply use `strcpy` instead of the first loop and `strcat` instead of the second loop?

Comment: This won't behave the way you expect if `l1`, `l2`, or their sum plus one are greater that `INT_MAX`. Perhaps you want to use `size_t`?

Comment: Both very good points. I considered strcpy, didn't consider strcat.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21880730/c-what-is-the-best-and-fastest-way-to-concatenate-strings

Comment: Found that interesting example when hunting for a reason not to use `strcat`.

Comment: Ok, just finished benchmarking everything. For 10,000,000 iterations, using two loops took 0.51s, using `strcpy` and one loop took 0.44s, and using `strcpy` and `strcat` takes 0.38s. This makes sense - the `strcpy` would provide the largest gain in efficiency, because it doesn't have to find the `null` terminator, but the `strcat` does, so it offers a marginal gain.

Comment: Yes, you are right that your previous code was, in principle, more efficient, because `strcat` has to walk over the first string again to find the end. Also, your previous code only wrote one null terminating character, so that was also more efficient. So actually, you had a good reason not to use the functions `strcpy` and `strcat`, even if it is probably better to use these two functions in this case, because simplicity is probably more important than efficiency for the question. However, in your current solution, the line `ret[l1+l2]='\0';` is no longer necessary.

Comment: The reason why `strcpy` and `strcat` are more efficient than your first solution, despite your solution being more efficient in principle, is probably that these two functions are heavily optimized on an assembly language level. Did you run your benchmark with full compiler optimizations active (`-O3` on most compilers)?

Comment: No - I used default optimization. Very very interesting stuff - I enjoy reinventing the wheel, so next time I should benchmark it with `-03` and see what I get!

Comment: @EvanHendler: Note that the flag is not `-03`, but `-O3`, i.e. the letter O, not the number. In your last comment, you wrote the number. It won't work if you use the number.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel trial and error - I would have gotten there ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225872/discussion-between-evan-hendler-and-andreas-wenzel).